# Cannot remove whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I know it shouldn't be asked, but I have a problem with kata, and I think that I've done everything correctly.

I've been trying to fix it by myself, but it has been some time on one problem and still nothing.

Here is the Kata:

> Complete the solution so that it strips all text that follows any of a set of comment markers passed in. Any whitespace at the end of the line should also be stripped out.
>
> Given an input string of:

```
apples, pears # and bananas 
grapes  
bananas !apples
```

> The output expected
>   would be:

```
apples, pears 
grapes  
bananas
```

And here is my code:

```
public class StripComments {

    public static String stripComments(String text, String[] commentSymbols) {
        String[] text2 = text.split("\n");
        String result = "";

        int symbolIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < text2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < commentSymbols.length; j++) {

                symbolIndex = text2[i].indexOf(commentSymbols[j]);
                if (symbolIndex >= 0) {
                    text2[i] = (text2[i].substring(0, symbolIndex)).replaceAll(" +$", "");
                }

            }

        }

        result = String.join("\n", text2);

        return result.replaceAll(" +$", "");


    }
}
```

The problem is, i cant get past trough attempt test

```
>  edges(StripCommentsTest)
expected:<a[
 b]
c> but was:<a[ 
 b ]
c>
```

And i do not know why. The space after b is always there, and if i tried to change something, it moves after c.

I think i've tried everything. Trim(), regex, nothing seems to work.

Could you please give me some hint?

The tests avaliable to view:

```
public void stripComments() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(
                "apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas",
                StripComments.stripComments( "apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples", new String[] { "#", "!" } )
        );

        assertEquals(
                "a\nc\nd",
                StripComments.stripComments( "a #b\nc\nd $e f g", new String[] { "#", "$" } )
        );
```

Comment: Well your problem description is incomplete.  What for example is considered a "comment marker?"  And what is a kata for that matter?

Comment: I don't see any logic in what is and isn't stripped out there... are they supposed to be in different lines?

Comment: Speaking of whitespace... please fix your code indentation so that it's legible.  Thanks.

Comment: edited my code, sorry

And catas are exercises from codewars site.

Comment: @DamianFabioMigus Now i see

Comment: @Nyerguds im spliting it into lines, then i remove everything after the comment symbol, and then i join it again. So im analizing the text line by line, because not every line has a "comment" and they may be different in all cases.

 I need to remove everything in the line after comment marker. And all whitespaces.

Comment: So comment markers are any non-alphanumeric characters, right?

Comment: @DamianFabioMigus Or can they also be dashes (-)?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the kata?

Comment: @sweeper https://www.codewars.com/kata/51c8e37cee245da6b40000bd


they can be only symbols, and hey are provided in the array commentSymbols

Comment: Can you please show the result you're getting now instead of the result of test?

Comment: It works fine for me : https://ideone.com/mKvZ3h

Comment: @YassinHajaj maybe there are some errors in the test, because i really have no idea how to change it.

The problem is, i can see only result of the test, not the input, so it's hard to even find on what case it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! I finally figured out your error.

Your code does not remove trailing whitespace *if there is no comment*.

Here's a test case:

```
System.out.println(stripComments( "a #b \nc \nd $e f g", new String[] { "#", "$" } ));
```

As you can see, there is a trailing space on the second line of the input - a `c` followed bye a space. Your solution does not remove that, but the kata requires you to (though I agree it's a bit unclear as to "when" to remove trailing space). Try editing your solution to remove trailing whitespace even if the line has no comments.

Anyway, here is my solution:

```
public static String stripComments(String text, String[] commentSymbols) {
    String[] lines = text.split("\n");
    // escape the comment symbols so that they can be used as regex
    List<String> escapedCommentSymbols = Arrays.stream(commentSymbols).map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++) {
        // create a regex that matches the comment portion of a line
        String regex = "(" + String.join("|", escapedCommentSymbols) + ").+$";
        lines[i] = lines[i].replaceAll(regex, "");
        // replace trailing whitespace even if it is not a comment.
        lines[i] = lines[i].replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
    }
    return String.join("\n", (CharSequence[]) lines);
}
```

Comment: But how do you explain the b appearing? It shouldn't right?

Comment: Which `b`? The `b` in the test case of the kata or the test case I created in my answer? @YassinHajaj

Comment: In the test results that Damian has posted

Comment: @YassinHajaj that was part of the input and is not after a comment symbol, so it should stay.

Comment: I don't get it.. But leave it, at least Damian has its answer.. I'm just curious but still it's a mystery for me lol

Comment: @YassinHajaj, I've just added one else codition to my code:


               `symbolIndex = text2[i].indexOf(commentSymbols[j]);
                if (symbolIndex >= 0) {
                    text2[i] = (text2[i].substring(0, symbolIndex)).replaceAll(" +$", "");
                }
                else{
                text2[i]=text2[i].replaceAll(" +$", "");}

            }

        }

        result = String.join("\n", text2);

        return result.replaceAll(" +$", "");`

Hope this will make it clear for you